# Comparing roots of two second-degree polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I would like to show that the largest root of a second-degree polynomial, i.e.,
$a_2 x^2+a_1 x +a_0$ is greater than the largest root of another, $b_2 x^2+b_1 x +b_0$.

Is there a way to show this without computing the roots themselves?

Comment: What conditions are given on the coefficients of the second degree polynomials?

Comment: $a_2$ and $b_2$ smaller than zero.

Comment: Surely you'd need some relationship between the $a_i$ and the $b_i$, otherwise it's just arbitrary.

Comment: I was mostly asking for techniques/tricks. But, my real problem is: $f\left(\gamma\right)=-2 \alpha ^2 \delta  (\gamma -1) (\gamma  (\delta  \mu +n-1)-\delta  \mu  n+n-1)-2 \alpha  \delta  \mu  n (\delta  \mu -2)+\mu  n \left(4-\delta ^2 \mu ^2\right)$ and $g\left(\gamma\right)=-2 \alpha ^2 \delta  (\gamma -1) (-\delta  \mu +\gamma +1)-2 \alpha  \delta  \mu  (\delta  \mu -2)-\delta ^2 \mu ^3+4 \mu$ with $\alpha\in\left(0,1\right)$, $\delta\in\left(0,1\right)$, $\mu\in\left(0,1\right)$, $n\geq 2$. From manipulating the roots, the largest root of $f$ >  the largest root of $g$.